# Retrieve and store text from H5 Element using Web Driver & C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to retrieve and store text from a Sub Header element on a web page.

The HTML from the page is as follows:

```
<h5 class="page-sub-header-com page-sub-header-subtext">Customer #8107 - NGP_APPLICATION_017</h5>
```

I would just like to retrieve the text "Customer #8107 - NGP_APPLICATION_017".

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be very easy with cssSelector

```
By css = By.CssSelector("h5.page-sub-header-com.page-sub-header-subtext");
string element = Driver.FindElement(css).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by Saifur

```
By css = By.CssSelector("h5.page-sub-header-com.page-sub-header-subtext");
string element = Driver.FindElement(css).Text;
```

Comment: kenito -no need to paraphrase the accepted answer as the little tick on saifur's answer indicates this